# ExtJs 4.2 Extend Custom Model using MVC problems

Tags: extjs, extjs4.2, wakanda

Using ExtJs 4.2 with MVC pattern

I am trying to make a custom model, store, proxy, reader, writer but am having problems getting it to work in the MVC pattern. I followed [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12877565/extend-from-custom-model-class-in-extjs-4) to extend a model and I can see it working only if it is not used in the MVC way.

My store refers to a model such as Contacts defined in the model property, then Contacts refers to custom model WakandaModel using the model property. But when I create my store which refers to Contacts none of the model properties or proxy defined in the custom WakandaModel is brought over to the stores model.

Here is my code, I have left comments in so you can see what I have attempted to try.  Thanks for any help!

App Code

```
Ext.Loader.setConfig({
    enabled : true,
    paths   : {
        'Ext.ux'    : "lib/extux",
        'Wakanda'   : "lib/extux/wakanda"
    }
});
Ext.application({
    name : 'SimplyFundraising',
    autoCreateViewport : true,

    requires : ['Ext.ux.Router', // Require the UX
    'Ext.window.MessageBox'],

    controllers : ['Contacts'],
});
```

Custom Model

```
Ext.define('Wakanda.Model', {

    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',

    idProperty: '__KEY',

    stampProperty: '__STAMP',

    defaultProxyType: 'wakanda',

    onClassExtended: function(cls, data) {
          //    debugger;
       // cls.apply(this)
//        var parts = data.$className.split('.');
//        var entity = parts[2]
//        var catalog = this.prototype.getCatalog(entity),
//            attributes = catalog.attributes;
//        for (var i = 0, l = attributes.length; i < l; i++) {
//            if (attributes[i].name === 'ID') {
//                attributes[i].persist = false;
//            }
//        }
//        attributes.push({name: this.prototype.idProperty});
//        attributes.push({name: this.prototype.stampProperty});
//       // data.fields = attributes;
//      //  debugger;
//        //this.setFields(data.fields)
//      // var mymodel = Ext.ModelManager.getModel(data.$className);
     //   debugger;
       // Ext.appy(this);
//        //this.superclass.superclass.$onExtended.apply(this, arguments);
    },

    getCatalog: function(className) {
        var catalog;
        Ext.Ajax.request({
            async: false,
            url: 'http://127.0.0.1:8081/cors/$catalog/' + className,
            success: function(response) {
                catalog = Ext.decode(response.responseText);
            }
        });
        return catalog;
    }

});
```

Custom proxy

```
Ext.define('Wakanda.Proxy', {

    extend: 'Ext.data.proxy.Rest',

   // alternateClassName: 'SimplyFundraising.data.WakandaProxy',

    alias : 'proxy.wakanda',

    sortParam: '$orderby',

    filterParam: '$filter',

    startParam: '$skip',

    limitParam: '$top',

  //  groupersParam: '$group',

    reader: 'wakanda',

    writer: 'wakanda',

    actionMethods: {
        create : 'POST',
        read   : 'GET',
        update : 'POST',
        destroy: 'POST'
    },

    buildUrl: function(request) {
        debugger;
        var modelName = this.model.modelName,
            operation = request.operation,
            records = operation.records || [],
            record = records[0],
            id = record ? record.getId() : operation.id,
            url = '/cors/' + modelName,
            action  = request.action;

        if (this.appendId && id && (action === 'read' || action === 'destroy')) {
            url += '(' + id + ')';
        }

        request.url = url;

        // console.log("buildUrl", this, arguments, request.url);


        if (action !== 'read') {
            if (action === 'create') action = 'update';
            else if (action === 'destroy') action = 'delete';
            url = Ext.urlAppend(url, '$method=' + action);
        }

        if (this.noCache) {
            url = Ext.urlAppend(url, Ext.String.format("{0}={1}", this.cacheString, Ext.Date.now()));
        }

        return url;
    },

    encodeSorters: function(sorters) {
        var min = [],
            length = sorters.length,
            i = 0, sort = '';

        for (; i < length; i++) {
            sort += sorters[i].property + ' ' + sorters[i].direction + ' ';
        }

        return sort;
    },

    encodeFilters: function(filters) {
        var min = [],
            length = filters.length,
            i = 0, filter = '';

        for (; i < length; i++) {
            filter += filters[i].property + ' eq ' + filters[i].value + '@ ';
        }
        return filter;
    }

});
```

Custom reader

```
Ext.define('Wakanda.reader', {

    extend: 'Ext.data.reader.Json',

    //alternateClassName: 'SimplyFundraising.data.WakandaReader',

    alias : 'reader.wakanda',

    root: '__ENTITIES',

    totalProperty: '__COUNT',

    getData: function(data) {
        if (Ext.isObject(data) && !data[this.root]) {
            data = [data];
        }
        return data;
    }

});
```

Custom writer

```
Ext.define('Wakanda.writer', {

    extend: 'Ext.data.writer.Json',

   // alternateClassName: 'SimplyFundraising.data.WakandaWriter',

    alias: 'writer.wakanda',

    writeAllFields: false,

    getRecordData: function(record) {
        var isPhantom = record.phantom === true,
            writeAll = this.writeAllFields || isPhantom,
            nameProperty = this.nameProperty,
            fields = record.fields,
            data = {},
            changes,
            name,
            field,
            key;

        if (writeAll) {
            // console.log("getRecordData1", this, arguments);
            fields.each(function(field){
                if (field.persist) {
                    name = field[nameProperty] || field.name;
                    data[name] = record.get(field.name);
                } else {

                }
            });
        } else {
            changes = record.getChanges();
            // console.log("getRecordData2", this, arguments, changes);
            for (key in changes) {
                if (changes.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
                    field = fields.get(key);
                    name = field[nameProperty] || field.name;
                    data[name] = changes[key];
                }
            }
            if (!isPhantom) {
                data[record.idProperty] = record.getId();
                data[record.stampProperty] = record.get(record.stampProperty);
            }
        }
        return {'__ENTITIES': [data]};
    }

});
```

Contacts Model

```
Ext.define('SimplyFundraising.model.Contact', {
    extend : 'Wakanda.Model' ,
    //constructor: function() {
        //alert(“Going to call parent’s overriden constructor…”);
     //   this.callParent(arguments);
       // return this;
   // }
});
```

Contacts Store

```
Ext.define('SimplyFundraising.store.Contacts', {
    extend : 'Ext.data.Store',
    model : 'SimplyFundraising.model.Contact',
    autoLoad : true,
    autoSync : true,
   // constructor: function() {
           // this.model = Ext.create('SimplyFundraising.model.Contact')

            //alert(“Going to call parent’s overriden constructor…”);
       // this.callParent(arguments);
        return this;
   // }
});
```

Contacts Controller

```
Ext.define('SimplyFundraising.controller.Contacts', {
    extend : 'Ext.app.Controller',
    models : ['Contact'],


    views : ['contacts.List', 'contacts.Edit'],
    init : function() {
        this.control({
            'contactslist' : {
                itemdblclick : this.editContact,
                removeitem : this.removeContact
            },
            'contactslist > toolbar > button[action=create]' : {
                click : this.onCreateContact
            },
            // 'contactsadd button[action=save]': {
            // click: this.doCreateContact
            // },
            'contactsedit button[action=save]' : {
                click : this.updateContact
            }
        });
    },
    list : function() {
       // var mystore = Ext.StoreMgr.lookup('Contacts');
     //   var myContact = this.getModel('Contact')
     //   var User = this.getModel('User');

        //debugger;
      //  var mystore =  Ext.create('SimplyFundraising.store.Contacts')

      //  var myContact = this.getModel('Contact').create()
    //   var bb =  myContact.create()

       // var rr = Ext.create('SimplyFundraising.model.Contact')
        var mystore =  Ext.create('SimplyFundraising.store.Contacts')
        debugger;
          //  mystore.proxy.api.read = users.proxy.api.read + '(17)'
        //mystore.proxy.extraParams = { $expand: 'ContactType'};
        mystore.load();
      //var test = Ext.ModelManager.getModel('Contact');

      // //var User = this.getContactModel();
      // User.load(258, {
    // success: function(user) {
        // console.log("Loaded user 258: " + user.get('lastName'));
    // }
// });
    },
    editContact : function(grid, record) {
        var view = Ext.widget('contactsedit');
        view.down('form').loadRecord(record);
        this.addnew = false
    },
    removeContact : function(Contact) {
        Ext.Msg.confirm('Remove Contact ' + Contact.data.lastName, 'Are you sure?', function(button) {
            if (button == 'yes') {
                this.getContactsStore().remove(Contact);
            }
        }, this);
    },
    onCreateContact : function() {
        var view = Ext.widget('contactsedit');
        this.addnew = true
    },
    // doCreateContact: function (button) {
    // var win = button.up('window'),
    // form = win.down('form'),
    // values = form.getValues(),
    // store = this.getContactsStore();
    // if (form.getForm().isValid()) {
    // store.add(values);
    // win.close();
    // }
    // },
    updateContact : function(button) {
        var win = button.up('window'), form = win.down('form'), record = form.getRecord(), values = form.getValues(), store = this.getContactsStore();
        if (form.getForm().isValid()) {
            if (this.addnew == true) {
                store.add(values);
            } else {
                record.set(values);
            }
            win.close();
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got this working now:

It looks like my custom wakanda model,proxy,reader,writer where not loading.  Still a bit confused on how MVC references classes and loads files and instantiates classes, which I asked in other question.

Any way the fix was to add a requires to the custom wakanda model and proxy

For the Wakanda model add requires: `['Wakanda.proxy']`,
For Wakanda proxy add requires: `['Wakanda.reader', 'Wakanda.writer']`,

now the inheritance is working as expected.